# Motion Blur effect Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-plugins

Can someone help me out please its my third day and i am not able to get help from anywhere i am new to jquery and i am working for a company where i am converting flash banners into html5 banner. I have converted everything but just image part is left.

I want to implement motion blue effect like  [this one](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/AdPreview.aspx?reportinteractions=0&adid=20986603) and here is my code [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/). If anyone can help me i would be grateful.

Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      bannerAnimation();
 });
function bannerAnimation(){
    //Jquery Animation
      $("#Image_Car").animate({ left: "30" }, 500, function () {
        $("#Image_Car").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
    });   
}
```

Comment: you 'this one' link is not working

Comment: can you try again please its a flash ad or if you cant see this then i have uploaded a video clip. you can download it from this link http://sharemobile.ro/file/769407 or if you still can not see it then i can email you the actual video clip i have recorded hope it will help :/

Comment: can some one tell me please?

Comment: Links are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use easing function [**libraries**](https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing) to aid your animations.
You can specify the easing function like this

```
$("#Image_Car").animate({ left: "50px" }, 1000,'easeOutElastic');
```

And for blur effect use `-webkit-filter: blur` support [list](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)

[**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/veDY6/3/)

Comment: thanks sarath but its a motion blur effect i need exact effect can you see the preview/?

Comment: it is sliding fast but it is not a windy effect can you see the demo link?

Comment: Please adjust those properties as you like , just change the number and play with it until you got an approximate effect , 100% replication is difficult , you need to use canvas for advance graphics effect.